# Can PHPUnit test stub methods not be overwritten?

Tags: php, phpunit

In my tests, I created a test stub for a class and mock the output of the method "save" to return a default value. I have this in my setUp() method to initiate before each test runs:

```
//  auth adapter
$this->authMock = $this->getMockBuilder('App\\Auth')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();

// by defaut, we'll make authenticate return a FAIL result
$this->authMock
    ->method('authenticate')
    ->willReturn(0);
```

This is then inject into my service locator overwriting the one used by the app (the real App\Auth). However, during the actual tests, I may wish to change the output of that method

```
// here, we'll make authenticate return a SUCCESS result
$this->authMock
    ->method('authenticate')
    ->willReturn(1);
```

Anyway, once I identified the issue, for POC, I just put these one after the other and right enough it seems that PHPUnit doesn't allow me to overwrite the previously declared mocked method return value:

```
//  auth adapter
$this->authMock = $this->getMockBuilder('App\\Auth')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();

// by defaut, we'll make authenticate return a FAIL result
$this->authMock
    ->method('authenticate')
    ->willReturn(0);

// here, we'll make authenticate return a SUCCESS result
$this->authMock
    ->method('authenticate')
    ->willReturn(1);
```

var_dump($this->authMock->authenticate()); exit; // returns 0 :(

I'm sure in the past I was able to do this. Unless it was a previous version of PHPUnit. Currently I'm using 4.8.*. Any way I can do this? By default I want authenticate to return FAIL, but some tests I may want to override this with SUCCESS (so act as though the user is authenticated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't recall ever being able to mock the same method twice, so what I usually do is define a helper function:

```
protected function mockAuthResult($result = 0) {...}
```

Another option would be to define:

```
protected $authResult;
```

And then in your `setUp`:

```
$this->authResult = 0; // fail by default
$this->authMock
    ->method('authenticate')
    ->willReturn($this->authResult);
```

And then you can override it for individual tests.

Comment: Actually, my real authResult (not the integer example I gave) is an object so would be passed by reference, so this approach could work for me. I'm not sure if arguments of willReturn method are passed by reference so would an integer work here? Anyway, thanks for the suggestion. I had this kinda in mind too but hoped I wouldn't require it. Is there any reason why phpunit won't allow mocked method to be re-defined? Maybe I can bring it up on their github page.

Comment: Now that I think about it, it probably isn't passed by reference so you might need to wrap it in a closure and use `willReturnCallback`

Comment: Oh, I've never used that method before. Thanks, seems useful.